# How can I change objects from inside the class?

Tags: python, oop, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree

I want to program several data structures and my objective at the moment is rotations in BST's. I've managed to do it a while ago, but by changing the values of the several Nodes and not changing the Nodes themselves. This is what I came up with, originally:

```
def _right_rotation(self, node):
        a = node.data
        z = node.right
        node.data = node.left.data
        node.right = Node(a)
        if not isinstance(node.left.right, Null_leaf):
            node.left.right.parent = node.right
        node.right.parent = node
        node.right.left = node.left.right
        node.right.right = z
        node.right.right.parent = node.right
        node.right.left.parent = node.right
        node.left = node.left.left
        node.left.parent = node
```

I hope the code is self-explanatory. node.parent is the parent of the node, Node is another class regarding the node, etc.

However, when doing Splay Trees, where I'll need to do several of these rotations, this can become a problem, because if I want to splay a node I'll need to do several rotations to it, but the node will point to the same place and in order to do, for example, 2 rotations on one node, I'll have to call

```
self._right_rotation(node.parent) 
self._left_rotation(node.parent.parent)
```

But that won't actually change the parents, and there are cases where a Node will be parent and grandparent of itself.

So I tried to do this:

```
   def _right_rotation(self, node):
        a = node.data
        z = node.right
        y = node.left.right
        node.left.parent = node.parent
        node = node.left
        node.right = Node(a)
        node.right.parent = node
        node.right.right = z
        node.right.right.parent = node.right
        node.right.left = y
        node.right.left.parent = node.right
```

Hopefully you can see what I'm trying to do here, and I know what the problem is. For example, by saying that node = node.left, I'm only changing the local variable node while not actually changing the node itself. Can you guys help me with this?

I'm not showing any more code (for splaying a node, for example), because it's part of an assignment and I'd like to do it by myself.

Edit:

Adding an example so it can become more clear:

```
tree = BST()
tree.insert([20,10,25,100,37,73]) #it just inserts nodes into a BST. The 
                                  #root is 20
tree._right_rotation(tree.root) #performs a right rotation on tree.root.
                                #the root is 10, and the nodes are                                 
                                #changed in conformity
```

However, if I use the second version of _right_rotation, the tree itself doesn't change, since there's a difference between saying node.data = node.left.data, which actually changes node.data outside of the function, and saying node = node.left, which doesn't change to where node is pointing to, it just changes the local variable node.

Comment: I don't think your code is self explanatory. Maybe if you add a simplified example of what you want to achieve more people would be able to help

Comment: @dzang Added an example, hopefully it can become more clear

Comment: what I meant is that you add a reproducible example. You can check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for guidelines on how to ask a question.
For example I still don't undersand what is your problem. For example you can give also some context, e.g. link this page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_rotation or better create a dummy simplified example that people can reproduce. If your question is clear, you'll get answers rapidly.